# How did Saint Anthony come to be the patron Saint of finding lost objects?

Tags: catholicism, intercession-of-saints, patron-saints

I’m not sure how many traditions see him this way but I know it is the case for Roman Catholics, especially Irish ones.

Answer (score 3):

**How did Saint Anthony come to be the patron Saint of finding lost objects?**

St. Anthony of Padua one day found the Psalter of someone. This lead others to invoke him as the **Patron Saint of finding Lost Objects**, after his death. It is that simple.

> [**Why is Anthony known as the patron saint of lost things?**](https://www.nationalshrine.org/blog/who-is-the-patron-saint-of-lost-things/#:%7E:text=Why%20is%20Anthony%20known%20as,patron%20saint%20of%20lost%20things.)
>
> > According to tradition, someone’s lost psalter was found following a prayer of St. Anthony. For this reason, he is known as the patron saint of lost things.

Comment: Did Saint Anthony find the psalter, or did the person find it after asking for him to pray to God on their behalf?